# Bluetooth speaker connects, but does not play music

Tags: audio, bluetooth

I seem tantalizingly close to getting my Beoplay P2 bluetooth speaker working with my Ubuntu / KDE laptop:

All the bluetooth utilities agree that the speaker is connected.  For example, `bluetoothctl`s startup output includes:

```
    [NEW] Device 04:FE:A1:4B:0F:EA Fenchurch
```

which is the speaker device.  (Its name is `Fenchurch`.)  When I ask for more details, what I get seems reasonable:

```
[bluetooth]# info 04:FE:A1:4B:0F:EA
Device 04:FE:A1:4B:0F:EA
    Name: Fenchurch
    Alias: Fenchurch
    Class: 0x240414
    Icon: audio-card
    Paired: yes
    Trusted: yes
    Blocked: no
    Connected: yes
    LegacyPairing: no
    UUID: Headset                   (00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Advanced Audio Distribu.. (0000110d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Handsfree                 (0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    Modalias: bluetooth:v0103p1005d0100
```

The KDE bluetooth configuration also claims that the speaker is connected, and the speaker itself has an indicator light that agrees.

The device appears in the Plasma audio volume widget:

[image: Volume widget shows Fenchurch with volume all the way up]

It also appears in `pavuctl`:

[image: pavuctl shows Fenchurch with volume all the way up]

Even more tantalizing, when I adjust the volume in `pavuctl`, the speaker itself makes an acknowledgement tone!  But this is the only sound I can get it to play.

Sound comes out of the laptop's builtin speakers just as I expect.

What should I investigate?  What is the next step?

---

Further information, or maybe red herrings:

- My phone can connect to the speaker and play through it with no difficulties.
- In fact, when I have Spotify open on my laptop and my phone, spotify can tell the phone to play music, which comes out of the connected bluetooth speaker!
- When I disable the phone's bluetooth connection so I'm sure the speaker is connected to the laptop, it displays a green indicator instead of a white one.  This means it is in “speakerphone” mode.  I'm not sure how this differs from being a regular speaker.

---

---

`alsamixer` says there is only one sound card.  It looks like this:

[image]

It's possible I could get it to recognize the P2 by entering the right name, but I don't know how to find the name.

Per the request below, here is the output of `systemctl status bluetooth`:

```
    ● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
       Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-07-27 11:09:02 EDT; 9min ago
         Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
     Main PID: 915 (bluetoothd)
       Status: "Running"
       CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
               └─915 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

    Jul 27 11:14:40 avocet bluetoothd[915]: Unable to register GATT service with handle 0x0017 for device 04:FE:A1:4B:0F:EA
    Jul 27 11:14:40 avocet bluetoothd[915]: Unable to register GATT service with handle 0x003d for device 04:FE:A1:4B:0F:EA
    Jul 27 11:15:21 avocet bluetoothd[915]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.56 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
    Jul 27 11:15:21 avocet bluetoothd[915]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.56 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
    Jul 27 11:15:21 avocet bluetoothd[915]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.77 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
    Jul 27 11:15:21 avocet bluetoothd[915]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.77 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
    Jul 27 11:15:41 avocet bluetoothd[915]: Unable to register GATT service with handle 0x000a for device 04:FE:A1:4B:0F:EA
    Jul 27 11:15:41 avocet bluetoothd[915]: Unable to register GATT service with handle 0x0013 for device 04:FE:A1:4B:0F:EA
    Jul 27 11:15:41 avocet bluetoothd[915]: Unable to register GATT service with handle 0x0017 for device 04:FE:A1:4B:0F:EA
    Jul 27 11:15:41 avocet bluetoothd[915]: Unable to register GATT service with handle 0x003d for device 04:FE:A1:4B:0F:EA
```

Here is the output of `journalctl -n 50`:

```
    -- Logs begin at Fri 2018-07-27 11:09:01 EDT, end at Fri 2018-07-27 11:17:01 EDT. --
    Jul 27 11:10:10 avocet org.kde.kdeconnect[1527]: kdeconnect.plugin.notification: removeNotification "0|com.spotify.music|2131363975|null|10143"
    Jul 27 11:10:10 avocet org.kde.kdeconnect[1527]: kdeconnect.core: "The remote host closed the connection"
    Jul 27 11:10:10 avocet org.kde.kdeconnect[1527]: kdeconnect.core: "The remote host closed the connection"
    Jul 27 11:12:31 avocet org.kubuntu.DriverManager[1527]: Traceback (most recent call last):
    Jul 27 11:12:31 avocet org.kubuntu.DriverManager[1527]:   File "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexec/DriverManager_DBus", line 24, in <module>
    Jul 27 11:12:31 avocet org.kubuntu.DriverManager[1527]:     import dbus
    Jul 27 11:12:31 avocet org.kubuntu.DriverManager[1527]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dbus'
    Jul 27 11:14:00 avocet org.kde.kdeconnect[1527]: kdeconnect.plugin.notification: Destroying NotificationsPlugin
    Jul 27 11:14:00 avocet org.kde.kdeconnect[1527]: kdeconnect.plugin.notification: Destroying NotificationsListener
    Jul 27 11:14:40 avocet bluetoothd[915]: Unable to register GATT service with handle 0x000a for device 04:FE:A1:4B:0F:EA
    Jul 27 11:14:40 avocet bluetoothd[915]: Unable to register GATT service with handle 0x0013 for device 04:FE:A1:4B:0F:EA
    Jul 27 11:14:40 avocet bluetoothd[915]: Unable to register GATT service with handle 0x0017 for device 04:FE:A1:4B:0F:EA
    Jul 27 11:14:40 avocet bluetoothd[915]: Unable to register GATT service with handle 0x003d for device 04:FE:A1:4B:0F:EA
    Jul 27 11:15:21 avocet sudo[3074]: pam_ecryptfs: pam_sm_authenticate: /home/mjd is already mounted
    Jul 27 11:15:21 avocet sudo[3074]:      mjd : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/mjd ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/pkill pulseaudio
    Jul 27 11:15:21 avocet sudo[3074]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by mjd(uid=0)
    Jul 27 11:15:21 avocet sudo[3074]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
    Jul 27 11:15:21 avocet bluetoothd[915]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.56 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
    Jul 27 11:15:21 avocet bluetoothd[915]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.56 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
    Jul 27 11:15:21 avocet rtkit-daemon[1654]: Successfully made thread 3091 of process 3091 (n/a) owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -11.
    Jul 27 11:15:21 avocet rtkit-daemon[1654]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
    Jul 27 11:15:21 avocet rtkit-daemon[1654]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
    Jul 27 11:15:21 avocet rtkit-daemon[1654]: Successfully made thread 3093 of process 3091 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
    Jul 27 11:15:21 avocet rtkit-daemon[1654]: Supervising 2 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
    Jul 27 11:15:21 avocet rtkit-daemon[1654]: Supervising 2 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
    Jul 27 11:15:21 avocet rtkit-daemon[1654]: Successfully made thread 3094 of process 3091 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
    Jul 27 11:15:21 avocet rtkit-daemon[1654]: Supervising 3 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
    Jul 27 11:15:21 avocet bluetoothd[915]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.77 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
    Jul 27 11:15:21 avocet bluetoothd[915]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.77 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
    Jul 27 11:15:21 avocet pulseaudio[3091]: [pulseaudio] backend-ofono.c: Failed to register as a handsfree audio agent with ofono: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.ofono was not provided by any .service files
    Jul 27 11:15:21 avocet rtkit-daemon[1654]: Successfully made thread 3096 of process 3096 (n/a) owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -11.
    Jul 27 11:15:21 avocet rtkit-daemon[1654]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
    Jul 27 11:15:21 avocet pulseaudio[3096]: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
    Jul 27 11:15:41 avocet bluetoothd[915]: Unable to register GATT service with handle 0x000a for device 04:FE:A1:4B:0F:EA
    Jul 27 11:15:41 avocet bluetoothd[915]: Unable to register GATT service with handle 0x0013 for device 04:FE:A1:4B:0F:EA
    Jul 27 11:15:41 avocet bluetoothd[915]: Unable to register GATT service with handle 0x0017 for device 04:FE:A1:4B:0F:EA
    Jul 27 11:15:41 avocet bluetoothd[915]: Unable to register GATT service with handle 0x003d for device 04:FE:A1:4B:0F:EA
    Jul 27 11:16:41 avocet kernel: input: 04:FE:A1:4B:0F:EA as /devices/virtual/input/input22
    Jul 27 11:16:44 avocet rtkit-daemon[1654]: Supervising 3 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
    Jul 27 11:16:44 avocet rtkit-daemon[1654]: Successfully made thread 3145 of process 3091 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
    Jul 27 11:16:44 avocet rtkit-daemon[1654]: Supervising 4 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
    Jul 27 11:16:44 avocet kernel: Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
    Jul 27 11:16:44 avocet kernel: Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
    Jul 27 11:16:44 avocet kernel: Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
    Jul 27 11:16:44 avocet kernel: Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
    Jul 27 11:16:44 avocet kernel: Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
    Jul 27 11:16:44 avocet kernel: Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0
    Jul 27 11:17:01 avocet CRON[3147]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
    Jul 27 11:17:01 avocet CRON[3148]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
    Jul 27 11:17:01 avocet CRON[3147]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

Answer (score 2):

Aha!  In `pavuctl` there is a button to connect a sound source such as `mplayer` to a particular output device:

[image]

Here it says “Built-in Audio Analog Stereo”.  But if I click it, a menu pops down:

[image]

Selecting “Fenchurch” makes the `mplayer` output come out of the P2.

I can do the same thing for Spotify.

I suppose the next step would be to understand how to get the system to prefer the P2 when it is available.  [This question seems relevant](https://askubuntu.com/q/113704/256219). But for now I have enough of a solution to go on with my day.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try unmuting the sound card via `alsamixer`?
Additionally can you share out from `systemctl status bluetooth` and `journalctl -n 50`?

Comment: Thanks for thinking about my question.  I added the information you asked for.

Comment: @MarkDominus In the alsamixer menu can you check if you press `F3`, and then navigate to the `headphones` tab, then press `m` to unmute, and finally move up the sound bar using up arrow key, something happens? Anyway I see that you solved the issue, just making sure that your headphone sound is not muted

Comment: I had actually checked that already. But thanks for the suggestion!